# Need help saving mp3 to SD card in Android

Tags: android, save, mp3

I am trying to make my Android app save a mp3 from the app to the sd card so it may be of use later, but it is not saving the file anywhere in the phone. In my AndroidManifest file, I have a permission to write external storage. 
Here is the code I have thus far:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        int ressound = R.raw.hodor1;
        saveas(ressound);
    }

public boolean saveas(int ressound){
     byte[] buffer=null;
     InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
     int size=0;

     //1st part
     try {
      size = fIn.available();
      buffer = new byte[size];
      fIn.read(buffer);
      fIn.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "IOException first part");
      return false;
     }

     String soundname = "hodor1";
     String filename = soundname +".mp3";
     String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
     File fullPath = new File(path, filename);

     boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
     if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

     //second part
     FileOutputStream save;
     try {
         save = new FileOutputStream(fullPath);
         save.write(buffer);
         save.flush();
         save.close();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "FileNotFoundException in second part");
         return false;
     } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "IOException in second part");
         return false;
     }    

     //not working
     //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

     File k = new File(path, filename);

     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, soundname);
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Elvis");
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

     //Insert it into the database
     Uri newUri = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

     // set as ringtone
     //savetype = RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE;
     //RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, savetype, newUri);

     return true;
    }
```

Comment: And what, precisely, is the problem you've encountered?

Comment: Fixed my post. It is not saving the mp3 file anywhere in the phone.

Comment: First, never hardcode paths. Please use `getExternalFilesDir()` or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` to find suitable places to write. Second, never use concatenation to create a `File` -- use the two-parameter `File` constructor. Third, **never silently ignore exceptions**. Use `Log.e()` to log them to LogCat. Then, examine LogCat to find the Java stack traces associated with those exceptions. Fourth, if you are going to use the `File` right away, you need to do more when you close the stream: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/saving-data-safely.html

Comment: I updated my code to reflect what you said and it is now saving sound. However, the last part about closing the file stream is confusing and I don't understand the post in your link about it. Could you explain please? I still have one issue, possibly related to this, where the saved sound is not the entire original, and just the first part of it.

Comment: The cutting out part fixed itself without me doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Commonsware answered my post the most accurately. Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() should be used along with the proper programming techniques like Logging and using the two parameter File constructor.